# C-like Array template specialization

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, struct

How can I write the template for generic array

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct Data<T[N]> {}
```

in a way that I can access it's elements by `[]` operator (or any other way)?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct Data;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Data<T>& val) {
    return val(os);
}

template <typename T>
Data<std::remove_cv_t<T>> data(const T& val) { return { val }; }

template <>
struct Data<int> {
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << val;
        return os;
    }
    const int& val;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct Data<T[N]> {
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            os << data(val[i]);
        }
        return os;
    }
    T val;
};
```

Error when accessing:

```
error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                    os << data(val[i]);
                               ^~~ ~
```

It seems that I should change `<T[N]>` for something like `<T(&)[N]>` to catch reference for the array, but I can't work it out.
Or maybe the `T val;` should be in `T* val;`, because the array is degenerating to pointer, so I can "catch" it?

**EDIT 1**

For `T val[N];` the error is:

```
error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'int const[2]'
Data<std::remove_cv_t<T>> data(const T& val) { return { val }; }
                                                    ^~~
```

**EDIT 2**

When I try to use

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Data<std::array<T, N> >
```

then it's doesn't correspond to any template.

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'PrettyPrint::Data<int [2]>'
    sstream << PrettyPrint::data(val);
               ^
```

Comment: I added the error from `T val[N]`.

Comment: Inside `Data<int[42]>` `T` is `int`, not `int[42]`.

Comment: So how can I formulate type for int[42] ?

Comment: should be working after the correction https://ideone.com/e.js/jwANgg

Comment: Hmm, what's wrong with `std::array`?

Comment: You want to declare `val` as `T val[N];`.

Comment: When in doubt, study how elders did: [libstdc++/array](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I tried that, but maybe I something wrong - (EDIT 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct template was

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Data<T[N]> {
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            os << data(val[i]);
        }
        return os;
    }
    const T(&val)[N];
};
```

What is the reason for `const T(&val)[N];`? I'm thinking about catching the reference in contrast to array degeneration to pointer, but I would be really glad if somebody explained it to me in greater depth.